# Encode and decoding German text in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, decode, encode

I am dealing with German text that I'd like to encode and decode to get rid of some characters. For instance, say I have

```
text = 'fÃ¼hrt - mÃƒÂ¶glich'
```

I would like to obtain:

```
corrected_text = 'führt - möglich'
```

If I encode `text` once using `cp1252` and decode the result with `utf8`, I get:

```
text.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
# 'führt - mÃ¶glich'
```

The first word is OK, but there remain some characters to replace in the second word. I can encode/decode a second time to get

```
text.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf8', 'ignore')
# 'fhrt - möglich'
```

This is now OK for the second word, but the first has a missing `ü`.

I could code and use this [debugging table](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html), together with `str.replace()`, to solve the above issue. However, I would like to know: given `text`, is there a way of using `encode` and `decode` to get `corrected_text`?

Comment: There is, but you have to split the text between the two words. Apparently, the two words have a different history of de-/encoding. Probably the second word was already mojibake when it was joined with the first, ready for a second round of mojibaking together.

Comment: You should have a look at the [fixes text for you](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/) library. Supposedly, it can handle strings with different encoding errors like your example, but only if the corresponding spans are on different lines. So if your actual data has a newline between "fÃ¼hrt" and "mÃƒÂ¶glich", things are looking good.

Comment: @lenz Great, thanks. This is the library I needed.

Comment: @lenz! Have been breaking my head for 2 days to fix encoding problem in my german text. Many thanks for your answer which let me solve my issue. Please post this as an answer and @unfolx make it as an accepteed answer so that it can help others as no proper solution is available in internet as of now.